# Error [not able to create c++ code] while installing Pyqt4 in miniconda in Linux

Tags: linux, pyqt4, python-3.6, miniconda

- Mini-conda
- Python 3.6.7

I am trying to install PyQt 4.10 and Sip 4.19.18. After I install

Sip successfully

```
python configure.py
make
make install
```

Then when i try to install

Pyqt4

```
python configure.py
```

This is the image of the error.
I am getting error and not able to install it is giving me error [not able to create c++ code.]

[image]

[Please don't give me negative vote because i really want to know what is happening.]

Comment: What's the exact error? Can you copy and paste it to the question?

Comment: @tayfun I have added my error now in the question.

Comment: @Code_Red show the error complete message

Comment: @eyllanesc I have posted the image of the error is it enough ??